# Url monitoring splunk

Tags: monitoring, splunk

I was monitoring 30 urls in splunk through data inputs . Out of which 1 url showing 500 error rest of the urls are working fine . When asked to user they replied it is working fine and URL is also correct what do I need to do

Answer (score 1):

Errors like that can be fleeting.  Just because Splunk sees an error doesn't necessarily mean others will.  Have your monitor report a problem only when an error repeats.

Comment: That something happens every day doesn't mean it isn't fleeting, but it would seem something is different between how Splunk accesses the URL and how users do so.  Finding that difference is key to making the monitor work better.

Comment: Sorry to ask this , how to find the difference

Comment: Do what Splunk does to get an error 500.  Then do what the user does to not get an error 500.  Compare the steps/commands/etc.  Contact the owner of the URL reporting the error to see what is causing the error.

Comment: There is no error from owner . It is up and running . In splunk it is showing error code 500

Comment: Understood.  So something must be different about Splunk connects.  Compare tcpdumps to see what that is.

Comment: could you please help to find tcpdump how to do it

Comment: Tcpdump is a Linux command that captures network traffic.  Work with your Linux admin to capture what goes over the wire when Splunk contacts the URL and when users connect to the URL.  Visually compare those two streams for a difference that might explain the error 500.

Comment: Ours is windows server

Comment: Then you'll need to work with your Windows admin.  :-)  You may need to install a tool like Wireshark to do the job, but I don't know enough about Windows to know if there is a built-in tool similar to tcpdump.

Comment: If it's not related to this question then you should click the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: No, you may not.